# Angularjs ui-routing multiple views using same controller with different resolves

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, resolve

I'm currently working on an application, where at some point we have a state with multiple inner views, each view has its own controller and resolves. Some controllers on this views are the same but the resolved value might be different. To illustrate and be more clear, here is an example config:

```
$stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  views: {
    '@': {
      templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
      controller: 'DashboardController'
    },
    'a@dashboard': {
      templateUrl: 'partial-a-dashboard.html',
      controller: 'InnerDashboardController',
      resolve: {
        dep: function() {
          return 1;
        }
      }
    },
    'b@dashboard': {
      templateUrl: 'partial-b-dashboard.html',
      controller: 'SomeOtherDashboardController'
    },
    'c@dashboard': {
      templateUrl: 'partial-c-dashboard.html',
      controller: 'InnerDashboardController',
      resolve: {
        dep: function() {
          return 2;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Now this works ok for ui-router 0.X but i'm trying to migrate this to 1.X and i see that resolves per views are not supported anymore, and than instead i should move resolve object to the state itself.. the problem comes for the 'InnerDashboardController'. If you see its used in 2 inner views, it expects a property called 'dep' but each view resolves it different (instance of the controller in view a will have dep as 1 and in c will have it as 2)

Whats the best way to update this to make it work on the new ui-router? Do i need to rename controllers and use different resolve properties? is there any other workaround available?